# Sorting a linked list alphabetically in C

Tags: c, list, sorting

I have written the following program to store input from a file in address format and sort the linked list alphabetically by city name as stored in a node. A sample input would be as follows:

```
Titus \n
Kollman \n
1522 Foggy Grove Loop \n
Wildcat NC 27507 \n
(252) 644-5477 \n
```

...etc

My code currently makes an unsorted linked list of all the entries correctly and I have written a sort function to sort the list alphabetically. When I try and sort the list, my code just continuously runs without outputting (gets stuck) and I can't find anything wrong with my sorting algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/* make node structure to store the data in */
struct entry {
    char fname[64];
    char lname[64];
    char city[64];
    char address[64];
    char cityandstate[64];
    char numb[64];
    struct entry* next;
};

/* function to add entry that will be used in sort*/
void addEntryForSort(struct entry* list, struct entry* x){
    struct entry* newNode = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    memcpy(newNode,x,sizeof(struct entry));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    while (list->next != NULL){
        list = list->next;
    }
    list->next = newNode;
}
/*function to find the minimum (alpha)of a linked list */
struct entry* findMin(struct entry* begin){
    struct entry* curr = begin;
    struct entry* min = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
    while (curr != NULL){
        if (strcmp(curr->city,min->city) < 0){
            min = curr;
        }
        else if (strcmp(curr->city,min->city))
            curr = curr->next;
    }
    return min;
}

/*sort function (attempt)*/
struct entry* sort(struct entry* top){
    struct entry* sorted = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    struct entry* min = findMin(top);
    struct entry* curr = top;
    while (curr->next != NULL){
        if (top == min){
            addEntryForSort(sorted,min);
            top = top->next;
            min = findMin(top);
            curr = top;
        }
        if (curr->next == min){
            addEntryForSort(sorted,min);
            curr->next = curr->next->next;
            min = findMin(top);
            curr = top;
        }
        else {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    addEntryForSort(sorted,top);
    addEntryForSort(sorted,curr);
    return sorted;
}


int main() {

    struct entry* head = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    char x[64];

    fgets(x,64,stdin);
    strcpy(head->fname,x);
    strtok(head->fname,"\n");

    fgets(x,64,stdin);
    strcpy(head->lname,x);
    strtok(head->lname,"\n");

    fgets(x,64,stdin);
    strcpy(head->address,x);
    strtok(head->address,"\n");

    fgets(x,64,stdin);
    strcpy(head->cityandstate,x);
    strtok(head->cityandstate,"\n");
    strncpy(head->city,head->cityandstate,strlen(head->cityandstate)-10);

    fgets(x,64,stdin);
    strcpy(head->numb,x);
    strtok(head->numb,"\n");
    fgets(x,64,stdin);

    int line = 7;

    struct entry* curr = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    struct entry* prev = head;
    head->next = curr;

    while (fgets(x,64,stdin) != NULL) {
        switch (line % 6){
            case 1:
                strcpy(curr->fname,x);
                strtok(curr->fname,"\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                strcpy(curr->lname,x);
                strtok(curr->lname,"\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                strcpy(curr->address,x);
                strtok(curr->address,"\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                strcpy(curr->cityandstate,x);
                strtok(curr->cityandstate,"\n");
                strncpy(curr->city,curr->cityandstate,strlen(curr->cityandstate)-10);
                if (strcmp(curr->city,"Old Roach MO 6") == 0){
                    strcpy(curr->city,"Old Roach");
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                strcpy(curr->numb,x);
                strtok(curr->numb,"\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                curr->next = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                break;              
        }
        line++;
    }

    curr=sort(head);
    while (curr!= NULL){
        printf("%s %s %s\n",curr->fname,curr->lname,curr->city);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens in the code? You could step through it using a debugger, or go old-school and insert printf statements at various places. From what you write, all you know right now is that it "gets stuck". All debugging is about narrowing it down more and more, and finally finding the error. For example, exactly where is your program stuck? Probably in a loop, but which one?

Comment: Don't cast the return from `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in this code.

First, you never initialize your structs, and malloc is not supposed to do it either, so the `next` member may not be null, making all the following code to fail. You should write:

```
struct entry* head = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
head->next = NULL;  /* ensure next is correctly initialized */
```

and next:

```
struct entry* curr = (struct entry*) malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
curr->next = NULL;  /* ensure next is correctly initialized */
```

You use strncpy to initialize `city` field. But strncpy does not add a terminating null, leaving your field unterminated. You should write:

```
strncpy(curr->city,curr->cityandstate,strlen(curr->cityandstate)-10);
curr->city[strlen(curr->cityandstate)-10] = '\0';
```

(same with `head` for first record).

In `findMin`, if two records compare equal, you will remain stuck there because you do not call `curr = curr->next`. It should really be:

```
/*function to find the maximum (alpha)of a linked list */
struct entry* findMax(struct entry* curr){
    struct entry* min = curr;
    while (curr != NULL){
        if (strcmp(curr->city,min->city) > 0){
            min = curr;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return min;
}
```

I get the maximum instead of the minimum, because to sort a singly linked list with a simple bubble sort, the simplest way is to sort it in place, taking the greatest element out of the list and putting it in first place in the resulting list. Moreover, this avoid to alloc new structs, because if you do not want to leak memory, you **must** free each and every allocated block. The `sort` function could become:

```
/*sort function (attempt)*/
struct entry* sort(struct entry* top){
    struct entry* sorted = NULL;
    while (top != NULL) {
        struct entry* max = findMax(top);
        if (max == top) { /* if max is first, simply increment top */
            top = top->next;
        }
        else { /* else make prev->next = max->next to remove max from the list */
            struct entry *curr = top;
            while (curr->next != min) curr = curr->next;
            curr->next = min->next;
        }
        /* and put current max in first place of the sorted list */
        max->next = sorted;
        sorted = max;
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Finally, you should free all allocated memory blocks by adding that at the end of main:

```
/* free all elements of the linked list */
while(head != NULL) {
    curr = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = curr;
}
return 0; /* never return random value to environment */
```

But if you want to do serious programming, you should also:

- test all input functions, here `fgets` should not return NULL and the buffer should have a `\n` as last character
- control the format of input fields (tel number, cities and zip code) - in particular, relying on a number of positions starting from the end of a string will fail if you do not have the proper count of spaces at the end of a line
- put the code for reading a record in a function, because you use it twice and you should learn to follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) best usage practice